# How to fetch tracked data from *mi Fit* Android app?

Tags: applications, xiaomi, app-data

I have a fitness tracker band from *mi (Xaomi)*. It has an Android app associated with it on my phone called *mi Fit*. Now, I want to know how to fetch all or some of the tracked data i.e sleep quality, steps taken, calories burned, distance covered etc. into a file that could be read by Windows or Android programs to create a graph out of it. If not, then is there any way to just combine and fetch the data?

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable for you to use a separate app to collect this data, take a look at [GadgetBridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge) (available [on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/nodomain.freeyourgadget.gadgetbridge/)). That's an open source app supporting many gadgets, a.o. Pebbles and Mi-Bands. It allows you to export the collected data (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/issues/1091)). Since v0.24 you can even set it up to do so automatically/periodically.